# Spring dependency injection to other instance

Tags: spring, servlets, dependency-injection

from the app-context.xml:

```
 <bean id="userDao" class="com.vaannila.dao.UserDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>  

<bean name="MyServiceT" class="com.s.server.ServiceT">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
</bean>
```

and inside ServiceT.java:

```
private UserDAO userDao;

public void setUserDao(UserDAO userDao){
    this.userDao = userDao;
}
```

the issue is: the setUserDao is called when the server goes on but when I call my doGet method:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    writer.write("hello");
    }
```

the userDao is null.
I put a breakpoint inside the setUserDao method and than another one inside the doGet method and saw that it is not the same insatnce... what is the reason? how can I fix it?
thanks!

Comment: Please post the code which shows how you inject your beans into the servlet.

Comment: Also post your `doGet` method body

Comment: You are not calling `new MyServiceT()` somewhere, aren't you?

Comment: it is being injected by the application-context (see the "MyServiceT" bean above).
I don't have to call new MyServiceT() since it is a servlet. just call the doGet using the browser (27.0.0.1:8888/MyServicT)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring is atowiring your bean correctly, the problem is that servlet container instantiates your servlet independently of spring. So you basically have two different instances - one created by spring and another created by container.

One workaround is to use `ServletContextAttributeExporter`, by putting the following in your app-context.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
 <property name="attributes">
     <map>
         <entry key="userDao">
             <ref bean="userDao"/>
         </entry>
      </map>
</property>
```

and then, in your servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    UserDao userDao = (UserDao)getServletContext().getAttribute("userDao");

    // do something with userDao

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    writer.write("hello");
}
```

another is to access the `WebApplicationContext` directly:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest reqest, HttpServletResponse response)
                                     throws ServletException, IOException {

    WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
    UserDao userDao =(UserDao)springContext.getBean("userDao");

 }
```

... or simply use Spring MVC and let it autowire everything like it should.

Also see [this blog post](http://andykayley.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-to-inject-spring-beans-into.html). It might be easier to convert your servlet to `HttpRequestHandler` and let it be served by `HttpRequestHandlerServlet`, both provided by spring.