# How use @Autowired instance variable use in ServletContextListener

Tags: java, spring

In Spring project, i used listener type of `ServletContextListener`. i have used instance field which is `@Autowired`, but i can't used autowired instance variable in `contextInitialized(event)` method, it throws `NullpointerException`.

How can use `@Autowired` for this

Comment: You would have to wire it manually; Spring does not create the listener your Java EE server does. How do you create your `ApplicationContext`? Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21914004/2071828).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `@Autowired` works only after context is initialized.

So you can do this hack:

```
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private MyBean myBean;    

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());
        this.myBean = (MyBean)ctx.getBean("myBean");
    }

}
```

or better solution would be thx to *Boris the Spider*:

```
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;    

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());
        ctx.autowireBean(this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Spring guarantees that it'll be initialized after the context initialization.

After it's initialized you can access it using:

```
MyClass myClass = ctx.getBean(MyClass.class);
```

In other words: you can't use `@Autowired` for making a contract which will force Spring to initialize your `Bean` before application context is finally initialized.