# simple spring jpa servlet example, crudrepository instance is null

Tags: spring

H i,  i am new to spring and what i am trying to do is create a simple application that does the following:

1- a simple crud on a simple oracle table, called Dummy, that has two fields: id, numeric and descripcion, a string

2 - the app only has a servlet. By invoking it the list of all Dummy rows are printed.

That's it. The problem is that in the servlet, my repository instance is always null.

Thanks

This is my code:

PersistenceContext

```
package jpa_spring.configuracion;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"jpa_spring.dominio"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceContext {
    @Bean(destroyMethod="close")
    DataSource dataSource(Environment env) {
        HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
        dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSourceConfig.setJdbcUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        dataSourceConfig.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
        dataSourceConfig.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

        return new HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, Environment env) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("jpa_spring.dominio");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));    
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto")); 
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy") ); 
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql")); 
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql") );

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;

    }
}
```

Dummy

```
package jpa_spring.dominio;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="DUMMY")
public class Dummy {    
    private Long id;
    private String descripcion;

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }
    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

RepositorioDummy

```
package jpa_spring.dominio;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface RepositorioDummy extends CrudRepository<Dummy, Long> {}
```

JPASpringServlet

```
package jpa_spring.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import jpa_spring.dominio.Dummy;
import jpa_spring.dominio.RepositorioDummy;

@Component
public class JPASpringServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Autowired
    private  RepositorioDummy repositorio;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Iterator<Dummy> it = repositorio.findAll().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Dummy d = it.next();
            System.out.println(d.getDescripcion());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your servlet is not a spring component, you can define a controller instead

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring MVC (and most likely you are), Spring already exposes a single servlet that will handle all http requests for you. As its role is to dispatch requests, it's called the DispatcherServlet. You can read more about it in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-servlet). That servlet will then use a `HandlerMapping` to map incoming requests to methods that should be called.

What you should do instead of creating a servlet is to create a [controller](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller). You can then use `@RequestMapping` annotation that will be picked up by the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, an implementation of `HandlerMapping`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. No, i am not using Spring MVC, i am trying to isolate just the JPA support. Will take a look to the docs suggested, but, if you were forced to use a servlet, a plain old one, ¿ how would you handle the situation ? thanks

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745770/spring-injection-into-servlet