# Spring Boot: Inject Bean into HttpServlet

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've got a Spring Boot where I've autoconfigured a Router bean.
This all works perfect but it becomes a problem when I want to inject that bean into a custom servlet:

```
public class MembraneServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Autowired
    private Router router;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        new HttpServletHandler(req, resp, router.getTransport()).run();
    }
}
```

This should be the way to go, but

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
```

won't autowire the Router because the `WebapplicationContext` is always null. The application is running in an MVC environment.

Comment: Is your httpservlet embedded by spring boot ?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745770/spring-injection-into-servlet ?

Comment: Have you considered using `@Controller` or `@RestController` instead of a servlet? I think it is a way more preferable way of doing things in spring-boot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you Spring Application Context is wired to the Servlet Context, you might want to pass ServletContext to [SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html#processInjectionBasedOnServletContext-java.lang.Object-javax.servlet.ServletContext-)

```
public class MembraneServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Autowired
    private Router router;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this, getServletContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        new HttpServletHandler(req, resp, router.getTransport()).run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about injecting 'Router' as constructor parameter.

So you would have this:

```
public class MembraneServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private Router router;

    public MembraneServlet(Router router){
        this.router = router;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        new HttpServletHandler(req, resp, router.getTransport()).run();
    }
}
```

then you can programatically create servlet registration like this:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean membraneServletRegistrationBean(){
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new MembraneServlet(),"/*");
}
```

Comment: That won't work because the HttpServlet is not instantiated by Spring.

Comment: sorry I've copied the OP's code and didn't removed the `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);` which is unnecessary if only the `Router` bean is needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Embedded server**

You can annotate with `@WebServlet` your servlet class:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/example")
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet
```

And enable `@ServletComponentScan` on base class:

```
@ServletComponentScan
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { ExampleApp.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class })
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApp
```

But injection with [@ServletComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/ServletComponentScan.html) will work only with embedded server:

> Enables scanning for Servlet components (filters, servlets, and
>   listeners). Scanning is only performed when using an embedded web
>   server.

More info: [The @ServletComponentScan Annotation in Spring Boot](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-servletcomponentscan)

**External server**

When using external server, mark `HttpServlet` class as `@Component`:

```
@Component
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet
```

And create configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = "com.example.servlet.package")
public class ServletConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ExampleServlet exampleServlet;

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean resetServletRegistrationBean(){
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(exampleServlet, "/example");
    }
}
```