# How to access the same instance of a bean from HttpServlet?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, dependency-injection

I am somewhat new to Spring Framework. I have a web application written with Spring (4.2.1). I'm trying to expose metrics using Micrometer library and will be scraping with Prometheus.

The relevant structure of the application is this:
 - core-module (JAR)
 - webservice-module (WAR)

I created a **PrometheusService** class which is a bean defined in core-module. Defined inside the bean is the `PrometheusMeterRegistry` and `Counter`:

```
@Service
public class PrometheusService {

    private static PrometheusMeterRegistry registry = new PrometheusMeterRegistry(PrometheusConfig.DEFAULT);
    private static Counter newAssetCounter = Counter
            .builder("new_asset_counter")
            .description("count of created assets")
            .tags("region", "na")
            .register(registry);

    public PrometheusService() {
        new JvmMemoryMetrics().bindTo(registry);
        new DiskSpaceMetrics(new File("/")).bindTo(registry);
        new ProcessorMetrics().bindTo(registry);
        new UptimeMetrics().bindTo(registry);
    }

    public static PrometheusMeterRegistry getRegistry() {
        return registry;
    }

    public Counter getNewAssetCounter() {
        return this.newAssetCounter;
    }

}
```

I created **MetricsResource** which is an **HttpServlet** that exposes the /metrics endpoint. When trying to `@Autowire` the PrometheusService bean, it was always null here. A quick search told me that **HttpServlet isn't managed by Spring**. If I wanted to `@Autowire`, I needed to add something like this:

`SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(webApplicationContext);`

Now, I was able to `@Autowire` the PrometheusService bean within the Servlet.

The `Counter` defined in the bean gets incremented within the core-module. The MetricsResource `doGet` method writes the metrics stored in the `PrometheusMeterRegistry`.

```
@WebServlet("/metrics")
public class MetricsResource extends HttpServlet  {

    private PrometheusService promService; // @Autowired
    private PrometheusMeterRegistry registry;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();

//        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(webApplicationContext);

//        promService = (PrometheusService) getServletContext().getAttribute("prometheusService");

//        WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
//        AutowireCapableBeanFactory ctx = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
//        ctx.autowireBean(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        resp.setContentType(TextFormat.CONTENT_TYPE_004);

        registry = promService.getRegistry();

        Writer writer = resp.getWriter();
        try {
            registry.scrape(writer);
            writer.flush();
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem though**, is that the value of the `Counter` is always 0 at the /metrics endpoint.

No matter if it's @Autowired or if I'm manually trying to get the bean.

How could this be? My PrometheusService bean is a singleton. Even the PrometheusMeterRegistry and the Counter are marked static, so why am I getting a different object in my servlet? After some more searching, I found that **Spring will create one singleton bean per container**. So what I'm assuming is happening here is there are two containers or contexts. A main application context and a servlet context.

Some things I've tried:
Making PrometheusService implement `ApplicationContextAware`
Using a ServiceLocator class that implements `ApplicationContextAware` and returns beans
Adding context-params to web.xml
Using `ServletContextAttributeExporter` in app-context.xml
Using `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext())`

I continue to get a new instance of the object. All I want to do is be able to create and expose custom metrics with Micrometer. Is my approach flawed? How can I access the correct bean from within my HttpServlet?

[Spring dependency injection to other instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127807/spring-dependency-injection-to-other-instance)
http://senthadev.com/sharing-spring-container-between-modules-in-a-web-application.html
[Spring dependency injection to other instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127807/spring-dependency-injection-to-other-instance)
[ApplicationContext and ServletContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931848/applicationcontext-and-servletcontext)

Comment: I think, it's needed to setup ApplicationContext in a ServletContextListener. Examples of code are available in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745770/spring-injection-into-servlet

Answer (score 0):

Try `processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(Object target, ServletContext servletContext)`.